# Технологии создания дистрибутивов Java приложений

Tags: java, swing, дистрибутив

Всем привет, вопрос про создание дистрибутивов для распространения десктопных Java приложений. На текущий момент у меня есть толстый клиент на Java + Swing + Maven, собирается всё соответственно в формате jar. Мне нужно собрать дистрибутив, чтобы можно было отдать пользователю и он смог его установить на своём ПК.

Есть такая штука как NSIS, но я задумался, может быть есть более удобный способ создать установщик. Хочется создать кроссплатформенный установщик или найти какой-нибудь плагин maven, который собирает сразу несколько установщиков для разных платформ: Win, MacOs, Linux.

Comment: Что подразумевается под "установить на своей машине"?

Comment: Поправил, вместо "установить на своей машине" - "установить на своём ПК"

Comment: У Java-приложений нет установщиков. Приложение отдельно, java (чтобы запустить приложение) отдельно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Варианты распространения программ на Java:

---

1. Обычное использование **jar ([runnable/executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974693/java-eclipse-difference-between-exporting-as-a-jar-and-exporting-as-a-runnable))**, подразумевающее то, что  у пользователя установлена ​​правильная версия java. В ином случае, пользователь получит ошибку в виде исключения: **class-file format version**. Наиболее распространенный способ.
2. Использование кросс-платформенной исполняемой оболочки Java - **[launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net)** и установщика **[NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)**. Такой подход дает большую возможность контроля.
3. Использование технологии от компании Sun Microsystems - **[Webstart](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start)**. Предполагается, что у пользователя установлена ​​правильная версия java.
4. Подход с применением сертифицированной реализации Java SE - [**Excelsior JET**](https://www.excelsior.ru/products/jet). Эффективна для крупномасштабного деплоя (развертывания), где нужно минимизировать проблемы с поддержкой.
5. [**Преобразование Java в EXE.**](https://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html) Java компилируется в независимый от платформы байт-код (файлы с расширением .class), которые напрямую не поддерживаются аппаратным обеспечением ПК. Таким образом, для выполнения Java-программы требуется среда выполнения Java (JRE), которая либо интерпретирует инструкции байт-кода, либо компилирует их в собственный код. Это, в свою очередь, означает, что автор этой программы должен каким-то образом обеспечить правильную версию JRE в каждой системе конечных пользователей.
6. Применение мультиплатформенного сборщика Java-инсталляторов - [**install4j**](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html) .
7. *[IzPack](http://izpack.org/)* - Создание установщиков под Windows, Linux, MacOS, бесплатный (Apache Software License, Version 2.0).

*[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/80597/8370915)*

**Плагины по сборке Jar-ников:**

- [Maven shade plugin](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-shade-plugin/):
- [Maven one-jar plugin](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-create-a-fat-jar-file-one-jar-example/):
- [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/):
- [Maven SetupBuilder Plugin](https://github.com/i-net-software/SetupBuilder.git):

Answer (score 1):

Всё необходимое обычно зипуется в простой архив, который пользователь самостоятельно распакует у себя на компьютере, обычно это ZIP, как самый распространённый. Не забываем вкладывать в архив командные файлы для запуска вашего приложения - bat/cmd для Windows bash/sh для Linux и MacOS и инструкции по настройке и запуску - readme.txt/pdf.