# Создание дистрибутива Java программы с embedded database из IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, развертывание

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли это?

Всё началось с моего вопроса: [Распространение Java приложения с базой данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1048274/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-java-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85/)

Где мне ответили, что: надо бы использовать встраиваемую бд.

Я выбрал базу (SQLite) и спросил: [Как работать со встраиваемой БД?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1052082/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%91%d0%94/)

И получил ответ: нужно класть в jar мою бд, а потом при запуске доставать бд и записывать её куда надо. И тут у меня возникает ещё один вопрос: даже если у меня это получится, после создания .deb файла(генерится при создании артефакта в IDEA) и установки приложения, структура каталогов будет другая и прав на запись не будет вовсе. Да и вообще, сам файл базы не понятно как кладётся в jar.

Если это не возможно сделать с помощью IDEA, то какие есть варианты сделать другим путём? Я смотрел: [Технологии создания дистрибутивов Java приложений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/859277/%d0%a2%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b2-java-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9)
попробовал install4j, но чёт ничего не получилось.

Я немного запутался. Как сделать всё правильно?

Comment: что значит `правильно`? Что ваша программа делать должна? У вас есть требования какие то?

Comment: @tym32167 JavaFX + hibernate приложение. Оно должно запускаться, это у меня получается, но, так же, работать с базой, а в этом и суть вопроса: как встраивать встраиваемую бд? Где её хранить и как программа будет себя вести после установки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку на последний пост отвечал я, то видимо мне теперь и отдуваться :)

Если бы я знал конечную цель, я бы конечно же сделал все по другому:

1. Упаковал Java проект в jar
2. Рядом нарисовал бы каталог куда положил БД (не в JAR)
3. Тут же положил батничек или shell скрипт для запуска jar
4. Все это обернул в ZIP архив

> ```
> mydistribution.zip
> \
> |myclass.jar
> |launch.sh
> |launch.bat
> --\db\mydb.db
> ```

И все. В этом случае - разворачиваете архив, запускаете скрипт/батник и все.